# Django model read and create in a query?

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to insert a row in Django model based on last id of model. My query is like,

```
Order.objects.create(group=123131, identifier=friendly_invoice.encode(Order.objects.last().id))
# group and identifier are unique together
```

I logged the queries as shown in http://www.dabapps.com/blog/logging-sql-queries-django-13/,

```
(0.016) SELECT `order`.`id`, `order`.`group`, `order`.`identifier`, `order`.`created`, `order`.`modified` FROM `order` ORDER BY `order`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1; args=()
DEBUG 2015-12-30 12:16:21,881 (0.016) SELECT `order`.`id`, `order`.`group`, `order`.`identifier`, `order`.`created`, `order`.`modified` FROM `order` ORDER BY `order`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1; args=()
DEBUG 2015-12-30 12:16:21,881 (0.016) SELECT `order`.`id`, `order`.`group`, `order`.`identifier`, `order`.`created`, `order`.`modified` FROM `order` ORDER BY `order`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1; args=()
(0.000) INSERT INTO `order` (`group`, `identifier`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES ('123131', '378ETGY', '2015-12-30 06:46:21', '2015-12-30 06:46:21'); args=[u'123131', '378ETGY', u'2015-12-30 06:46:21', u'2015-12-30 06:46:21']
DEBUG 2015-12-30 12:16:21,881 (0.000) INSERT INTO `order` (`group`, `identifier`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES ('123131', '378ETGY', '2015-12-30 06:46:21', '2015-12-30 06:46:21'); args=[u'123131', '378ETGY', u'2015-12-30 06:46:21', u'2015-12-30 06:46:21']
DEBUG 2015-12-30 12:16:21,881 (0.000) INSERT INTO `order` (`group`, `identifier`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES ('123131', '378ETGY', '2015-12-30 06:46:21', '2015-12-30 06:46:21'); args=[u'123131', '378ETGY', u'2015-12-30 06:46:21', u'2015-12-30 06:46:21']
```

This is creating two sql queries in db. I believe this will give error if this code is executed by two parallel request.

How can I write this query in safer way?

Comment: I think we need some more info about `friendly_invoice`.

Comment: It is a function which will encrypt id into alphanumeric values. It hides id from user and show him/her a aplhanumeric string.

Comment: Do you decode and encode every time you have to make a query? I sense a bigger problem here.

Comment: No. It is used only to show user. internally id are used everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/#savepoints

```
from django.db import transaction

# open a transaction
@transaction.atomic
def viewfunc(request):
   ...
```